# Barnes beta - like integral mistake

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Consider the Barnes beta like integral: Where Re$(a)$ ,Re$(b)$ is greater than $0$ and $c$ is not a negative integer, where $|z|<1$ and $|$arg$(-z)$|$<\pi$,
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-i\infty}^{i\infty}\frac{\Gamma(a+s)\Gamma(b+s)\Gamma(-s)}{\Gamma(c+s)}(-z)^s\, ds$$

Since there is a simple pole to $0$. I computed it using the right-side semicircle contour with a left-side semicircle $\epsilon$ away from the origin. Traversed clockwise. Call the whole contour $C$

Naming the Bigger arc $\Gamma$, smaller arc $\gamma_\epsilon$,

I have no trouble proving $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma}\frac{\Gamma(a+s)\Gamma(b+s)\Gamma(-s)}{\Gamma(c+s)}(-z)^s\, ds$ tends to zero as $\Gamma$ gets larger and larger.

Using the Residue theorem:(Since the contour is oriented clockwise)

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C}{\underbrace{\frac{\Gamma(a+s)\Gamma(b+s)\Gamma(-s)}{\Gamma(c+s)}(-z)^s}_{f(s)}}\, ds=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathbf{Res}(f,s=n)$$
$$=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(a+n)\Gamma(b+n)}{\Gamma(c+n)}(-z)^n\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n!}=\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(c)}{}_2F_1(a,b;c;z)$$

Now computing $\int_{\gamma_\epsilon}f$, letting $s=\epsilon e^{-i\theta}$ and $s=-u$ gives $$=\int_{-3\pi/2}^{-\pi/2}f(\epsilon e^{-i\theta})(-i\epsilon e^{-i\theta})\, d\theta=-\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}\frac{\Gamma(a+\epsilon e^{iu})\Gamma(b+\epsilon e^{iu})\Gamma(-\epsilon e^{iu})}{\Gamma(c+\epsilon e^{iu})}(-z)^{\epsilon e^{iu}}i\epsilon e^{iu}\, du$$

Now letting epsilon go to zero:
$$\int_{\gamma_{\epsilon}}f(s)\, ds=\pi i\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(c)}$$

Since integrating on $C-\Gamma-\gamma_\epsilon$ gives the result.

We subtract the integrals to get the answer $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-i\infty}^{i\infty}\frac{\Gamma(a+s)\Gamma(b+s)\Gamma(-s)}{\Gamma(c+s)}(-z)^s\, ds=\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(c)}\Big({}_2F_1(a,b;c;z)-\frac{1}{2}\Big)$$

However, the correct result should be $\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(c)}{}_2F_1(a,b;c;z)$.

I found many derivations and it seems that they didn't compute $\gamma_\epsilon$.

Why is that? (I feel like I got something wrong conceptually)

Reference:  [Derivation I found on the internet](https://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwii4qP5z5n_AhUYplYBHVLUBKAQFnoECA0QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fhomepage.tudelft.nl%2F11r49%2Fdocuments%2Fwi4006%2Fbarnes.pdf&usg=AOvVaw38z_-EB-Xr6Ub9nP5lGCMg)

Comment: What are the hypotheses on $z$?

Comment: I'm not immediately convinced the integral around $\Gamma$ vanishes. There are three potentially large terms on the numerator and only one compensating large term on the denominator. I can't remember my $\Gamma$-function asymptotics but it seems dubious

Comment: @FShrike $|z|<1$, I'll add the condition in the post

Comment: This is exactly the derivation I found on the internet, my confusion is why did he not compute the semi-circular circle around the origin

Comment: Mathematica gives the residue of $$\frac{\Gamma(a+s)\, \Gamma(b+s)\, \Gamma(-s)}{\Gamma(c+s)}\, (-z)^s$$ at $s=n$ where $n\in\mathbb{Z}\land n\geq 0$ as $$-\frac{\Gamma(a+n)\, \Gamma(b+n))}{\Gamma(c+n)} \frac{z^n}{n!}$$ and simplifies the residue sum as $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} -\frac{\Gamma(a+n)\, \Gamma(b+n))}{\Gamma(c+n)} \frac{z^n}{n!}=-\Gamma(a)\, \Gamma(b) \, _2\tilde{F}_1(a,b;c;z)$$ where $_2\tilde{F}_1$ is the [Hypergeometric2F1Regularized](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1Regularized/) function.

Comment: this is similar to the derivation I found, however, you can’t simply sum the residue at $z=0$, since there is a pole on it. Instead integrating through it, You have to construct a detour

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the statement $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-i\infty}^{i\infty}\frac{\Gamma(a+s)\Gamma(b+s)\Gamma(-s)}{\Gamma(c+s)}(-z)^s\, ds$$ incudes the contour $\gamma_\epsilon$. So I did not have to subtract it.

See [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/448621/a-mistake-on-a-barnes-beta-like-integral)